# How to get the xr.Dataset coordinates as string?

Tags: python, dataset, python-xarray

I created a xarray.Dataset. In the Dataset, I would like to get a list of a certain corrdinate.

A sample code is shown below. In the code, the dataset 'ds' contains 4 of 'MachineType', namely 'MC_A', 'MC_B', 'MC_C', and 'MC_D'.
I would like to get them as string, so that the last for-loop executes 'MC_A','MC_B','MC_C','MC_D'.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.linspace(0,1500,16)
y1 = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1,1,6,len(x)))
y2 = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1,1,6,len(x)))
y3 = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1,1,6,len(x)))
y4 = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1,1,6,len(x)))

da1 = xr.DataArray(y1, dims=('MachineID','MachineType','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'),
                       coords={'MachineID':['MC_A'],'MachineType':['Car'],'Year':['2020'],'Month':['Aug'],'Compensation':[1],
                            'Axis':['X'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x},
                       name='val')

da2 = xr.DataArray(y2, dims=('MachineID','MachineType','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'),
                       coords={'MachineID':['MC_B'],'MachineType':['Car'],'Year':['2020'],'Month':['Aug'],'Compensation':[1],
                            'Axis':['X'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x},
                       name='val')

da3 = xr.DataArray(y3, dims=('MachineID','MachineType','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'),
                       coords={'MachineID':['MC_C'],'MachineType':['Train'],'Year':['2020'],'Month':['Aug'],'Compensation':[1],
                            'Axis':['X'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x},
                       name='val')

da4 = xr.DataArray(y4, dims=('MachineID','MachineType','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'),
                       coords={'MachineID':['MC_D'],'MachineType':['Train'],'Year':['2020'],'Month':['Aug'],'Compensation':[1],
                            'Axis':['X'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x},
                       name='val')

#%%
df = pd.concat([da1.to_dataframe(), da2.to_dataframe(), da3.to_dataframe(), da4.to_dataframe()])
ds=xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)
ds


#%% This part is not working as I want
for machineid in ds['MachineID']:
    print(machineid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.values` in the print command and change the type to `str`:

```
for machineid in ds['MachineID']:
    print(str(machineid.values))
```